# Why am I getting different time complexities in these two different nested for-loops?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

Ok, so I know two nested for-loops each incrementing by 1 gives a quadratic time complexity. Then I was curious to see if I change the update of one of the loops incrementing by a multiplication of 2 would I get O(n log n) instead of O(n^2) and vice versa to the other loop.

In each inner loop I have a variable to count how many times the loop executes. The array is size 2^20 so 1,048,576. I'm thinking both methods should have the same complexity of n log n (20 * 1,048,576). But only Algorithm 2 gets close to that complexity and Algorithm 1 has a complexity of n * 2.

To my understanding one loop is O(n) and the other is O(log n) so it should be O(n log n) together and then if I switch them I should get a complexity of O(log n n) which would be the same thing.

```
 int[] arr = new int[1048576];

    // Algorithm 1
    int counter1 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j *= 2) {
            counter1++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter1);

    // Algorithm 2
    int counter2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i *= 2) {
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            counter2++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter2);

    // counter1: 2097130 (n * 2)
    // counter2: 19922945 (n log n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple math. Assume for now, that `w *= 2` will essentially take 20 steps to reach roughly 1 million.

Algo 1 will run roughly 1 million j-loops, but those loops will only take about 20 j-steps each to complete. You're running the inner loop on algo 2 (especially the first time) on a factor of millions, whereas the other will run <=20 times, 1 million times. **However, you need to account for the decay**, especially at the start. By the time you've hit `i=2`, you're already down to 19 j-steps on the algorithm. By 4, you're down to 18, and so on. This early decay will essentially "kill" the momentum for the number of steps. The last ~500,000 "i-steps" will only increment the counter once.

Algo 2 runs 1 million j-steps the first run alone, followed by another (i-step-1) j-steps (1, followed by 2, followed by 4, etc). You're running a million steps roughly each time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the number of passes in each loop for the second algorithm. Let's take `N=arr.length`.

First the outer most loop. i ranges from 1 to N, and multiplied by 2 each time, that makes `log(N)` iterations.

Then, in the inner most loop j ranges from i to N and is incremented by 1 each time, that makes (N-i) iterations.

Lets now take `k=log(i)`. So the total number of times counter2 is incremented is `sum(N-2^k) for k=0 to log(N)`

Sum for k=0 to log(N) of 2^k is a geometrical sum that adds up to 2^(log(N)+1)-1 so 2N-1.

Therfore the total complexity of the second loop is Nlog(N)-2N+1 which is O(Nlog(N)) just like your first loop.

The difference is the second order term 2N. If we push our development we have for the first loop a complexity of:

```
Nlog(N) + O(1)
```

and for the second:

```
Nlog(N) - 2N + O(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Both solutions you posted have exactly the dame complexity, i assume u forgot to swap the inner for loop begin clause variables.

O (n^2) with a constant factor.
Big-O notation works like this:

n/2 * n is the time your loop needs (any of the two u posted)

-> 1/2 * n * n = 1/2 * n^2

1/2 is the factor.
Complexity is polynomial, n^2

Comment: these are not the same time complexity, because the two loops are not equivocal `n`. It's `O(n(*2))` (may be roughly off on that) vs `O(n*log(n))`  because of the exponential decay from the first algorithm killing off additional steps.